# Is $ f \circ g $ invertible in the diagram below?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, inverse, function-and-relation-composition

I was working through [Can the composition of two non-invertible functions be invertible?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1169039/can-the-composition-of-two-non-invertible-functions-be-invertible) For the image below is $f \circ g$ invertible?

[image: The arrows signify mapping. I have not drawn the nodes but assume they are present.]

Thanks!

Comment: if (f o g) is invertible then so is g, thus, strictly speaking, your example is not the composition of "two non-invertible" functions but rather of "an invertible and a nob-invertible function".

Comment: @D.F.F The original question in the text ask for a counter example for Suppose that f and g are functions and f ◦ g is invertible. Then f and g are invertible. I don't think both can be non invertible or can they be?

Comment: They can't as the injectivity of f o g implies that g is injective as well.

Comment: @D.F.F Actually, since invertible means bijective, yes, they can both be non invertible. And the example shows this. $g$ is not invertible.

Comment: @ 5xum I assumed invertible means injective (which makes sense if a function is understood as a set of ordered pairs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, good job! You've correctly constructed a counterexample that demonstrates how $f \circ g$ can be invertible even though $f$ is not invertible (since $f$ only needs to be invertible when its domain is restricted to the range of $g$).

Answer (score 0):

Your counterexample is good.

You can see in your example the two properties in action:

- If $f\circ g$ is surjective, then $f$ must be surjective (and yours *is*), but $g$ doesn't need to be surjective (and yours *is not*)
- If $f\circ g$ is injective, then $g$ must be injective (yours *is*), but $f$ does not need to be injective (yours *is not*)

Comment: In the last sentence you wrote g twice.